# Ошибка с преобразованием строки в число

Tags: java, исключения

```
private char whatThing() {
    double random = Math.random();
    String f = String.format("%.2f", random);
    double formattedRandom = Double.parseDouble(f);
    if(formattedRandom < 0.33) {
        return 'R';
    } else if(formattedRandom >= 0.33 && formattedRandom < 0.66) {
        return 'P';
    } else {
        return 'S';
    }
}
```

Выводит ошибку NumberFormatException:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>       "0,47"
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
>           at RPSEngine.whatThing(RPSEngine.java:28)
>           at RPSEngine.(RPSEngine.java:8)
>           at RPSSheath.(RPSSheath.java:30)
>           at RPSSheath.main(RPSSheath.java:43)

Comment: вы хотите равномерно выбрать из 3 возможных вариантов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант делает тоже самое, но проще

```
private char whatThing() {
    final Random random = new Random();
    int choice = random.nextInt(2);
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            return 'R';
        case 1:
            return 'P';
        default:
            return 'S';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить число с точностью до двух цифр после запятой, нужно указать следующее выражение:

> %1$,.2f

Таким образом код будет выглядеть так:

```
double number = Math.random();
String str = String.format("%1$,.2f", number);
System.out.println(number);
System.out.println(str);
```

> 0.3086820994984767
>   0.31

Comment: Дело в том, что я работаю с java swing, и программа все равно выдает ту же ошибку.